# ¿Cómo excluir registros de una tabla con SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo 2 tablas: `Informe` y `Examen`

La tabla `Examen` contiene los siguientes campos:

- CodExamen(PK, int, not null)
- Descripcion(varchar(50), null)

Mientras que la tabla `Informe` contiene los siguientes campos:

- id(PK, int, not null)
- CodExamen(PK, FK, int not null)

Por ende, en cada registro de `Informe` hay asociado al menos un registro de `Examen`.

Lo que necesito hacer es que dado un `id` de la tabla `Informe` quiero que SQL Server me muestre todos los registros de `Examen` que **NO** están incluidos en la tabla `Informe`.

Ejemplo: En la tabla `Examen` tengo los siguientes registros:

- 1, Examen1
- 2, Examen2
- 3, Examen3
- 4, Examen4
- 5, Examen5

En la tabla `Informe` tengo estos registros:

- 1, 1
- 1, 2
- 1, 4

Lo que quiero que me muestre serían todos los registros de `Examen` que no estén en `informe.id=1`, es decir que muestre

- 3, Examen3
- 5, Examen5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más eficiente es un `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DECLARE @idInforme int = 1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Examen e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Informe
                 WHERE id = @idInforme
                 AND CodExamen = e.CodExamen)
;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!